# Divs don't display in the same line on Firefox 

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and custom CSS to develop my personal website and I have the following HTML code to generate the content part with two columns.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="content" class="span9">
        content
    </div>
    <div id="ads" class="span3">
        ads
    </div>
</div>
```

This works in all browser, but with the following CSS, the ads div goes under the content div when viewed in Firefox. In all other browsers, the ads div keeps in the right side of content div (this is the correct display).

```
#content{
    margin-top:2em;    
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    border: 2px solid #EEF;
}

#ads{
    margin-top:2em;            
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:15px;
    border: 2px solid #EEF;
}
```

I think this happens because the padding + border, but all other browsers displays correctly. So, there is a way to fix this in Firefox?

If needed, this error can be viewed in http://www.dinhani.com.br (sorry, content is in portuguese because development started these days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't implement `box-sizing` without a `-moz-` prefix.  See [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243412)

Also, your question missed the most important CSS rules: i.e. the `width` of each `div`.  The page you link to shows rules for `.row-fluid > .span3` and another for .span9

Comment: The width is defined by span3 and span9 classes of Bootstrap. It uses a grid of span12 (12 columns).

Answer (score 0):

You change your html like this (just small changes in div start tag.
and I hope you get our output like image below

```
<div class="row-fluid">
     <div id="content" class="span9">
         content
     </div>
     <div id="ads" class="span3">
         ads
     </div>
 </div>
```

[image]
ok you want to like this image2

```
#content{
    margin-top:2em;    
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 20px ;
    border: 2px solid #EEF;
    float:left;
}

#ads{
    margin-top:2em;            
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:15px;
    border: 2px solid #EEF;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the error in the div here is StackOverflow ocurred when I was pasting the code. The code in the server is correct. Plus, the desired visualization is the ads div in the right side of the content div, not below.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this fiddle can help you http://jsfiddle.net/9Zf8U/1/ I just added firefox css hack here and nothing eals.

Comment: Please, can you explain better what do you did?

Answer (score 0):

Adding css hacks for (moz browser) only.